# How to merge discontinuous selection (when using Ctrl) in a range in VBA on Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to retrieve some cell addresses with my code. But since the selection is discontinuous it seems like that .Cells doesn't work well.

As you can see in the screenshot, I ask the user to select two rows, the selection is the yellow area (rows number 7 & 9)
[image: screenshot excel file]

when entering my code :

```
Sub test()

Dim rangeselected As range


Set rangeselected = Application.InputBox("Select the quarters range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

Debug.Print rangeselected .Cells(1, 1).Address

Debug.Print rangeselected .Cells(2, 1).Address

End Sub
```

I thought that I will have as a result for the debug.print command : E7 & E9 but instead I get E7 & E8

I don't understand why I get the good result for the first one and not the second one.

I know that in order to have the the good result I should write :

```
Debug.Print rangeselected .Cells(3, 1).Address
```

But what can I do in order to get the rows to "follow" each other in the rangeselected variable ?

Because in the selection there are only two rows so I'm a little bit confused.
I hope that my question is clear enough, thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Cells(r, c)` property of a range object acts very simply, offsetting r ans c from the beginning of the range. You can even give offsets that fall outside the range!

Obviously, this is not adequate to iterate over a `Multi-area range`. Well, the solution is to iterate over the `.areas` of the `Multi-area range`.

```
Dim rangeselected As range
Set rangeselected = Application.InputBox("Select the quarters range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

For each area in rangeselected.Areas
    For each cel in area.Cells '<-- could be also area.Rows, area.Columns...

    Next cel
Next area
```